# How many equivalence relations over $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ satisfy: $[\{8\}]_S=\{A\in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)|A\neq \{1\}\wedge A\neq \{2\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, notation, equivalence-relations

> How many equivalence relations $S$ over $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ satisfy:
>
> $$[\{8\}]_S=\{A\in \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\mid A\neq \{1\}\wedge A\neq \{2\}\}$$

Just to make sure I understand, the question asks to find the cardinality of a quotient set $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)/S$?

Then I can build a bijection: $f(X)=\begin{cases}\{n+3\} &,X=\{n\}\\ X &,else \end{cases}$ which satisfy the above condition so the cardinality is $\aleph$.

Comment: Don't you mean "equivalence relations" in stead of "equivalence classes"?

Comment: @drhab yes, fixed.

Comment: As stated, the question ask for the cardinality of the set $\{S \subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N)^2 : \forall x \in \mathcal P(\mathbb N),\, (x,\{8\}) \in S \iff x \notin \{\{1\},\{2\}\}\}$. Also, the rest of your post has no meaning : $f$ is not a bijection ($\{0\}$ is not in the image) ; what do you possibly mean by "f satisfy the above condition" when the above condition is not about maps… Finally $\aleph$ (without index) does not denote any specific cardinal.

Comment: We use $\aleph$ instead of $\aleph_1$. I see I didn't understand the question, but I do need a function in order to find the cardinality of this set no? @Pece

Comment: @GinKin I'm guessing you mean $\aleph_0$ (the cardinality of the natural numbers), not $\aleph_1$ (the smallest uncountable ordinal). You don't usually need to actually find a function for finite sets since you can just count the number of elements so the function is "obvious".

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I meant the cardinality of the reals...

Comment: @GinKin I see... That's a weird convention. BTW, the cardinality of the reals is ${\frak c}=2^{\aleph_0}$ which is not necessarily equal to $\aleph_1$ (although $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\aleph_1$); the assumption that it is is called the continuum hypothesis and is independent of ZFC.

Comment: I thought there is no cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $c$... @MarioCarneiro

Comment: @GinKin: The claim that there is no cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak c$ _is_ the continuum hypothesis. It is known to be independent of the axioms of ZFC set theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a natural bijection between equivalence relations and the partitions generated by the classes, so we can equivalently ask how many different partitions of ${\cal P}(\Bbb N)$ contain $\{A\in {\cal P}(\Bbb N)\mid A\neq \{1\}\land A\neq \{2\}\}$ as a member. (The part about $\{8\}$ is not relevant because clearly $\{8\}$ is in the above set, it is just showing one representative of this equivalence class.)

So we are left to partition the remainder of ${\cal P}(\Bbb N)$ after taking away everything in this set. The remainder is $\{A\in {\cal P}(\Bbb N)\mid A=\{1\}\lor A=\{2\}\}=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, and there are only two ways to partition this, as one set and as two sets, yielding two partitions:

$$P_1=\{\{\{1\}\},\{\{2\}\},\{A\in {\cal P}(\Bbb N)\mid A\neq \{1\}\land A\neq \{2\}\}\}$$
$$P_2=\{\{\{1\},\{2\}\},\{A\in {\cal P}(\Bbb N)\mid A\neq \{1\}\land A\neq \{2\}\}\}$$

which correspond to the equivalence relations

$$x\,S_1\,y\iff x=y=\{1\}\lor x=y=\{2\}\lor x,y\in\{A\in {\cal P}(\Bbb N)\mid A\neq \{1\}\land A\neq \{2\}\}$$
$$x\,S_2\,y\iff x,y\in\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\lor x,y\in\{A\in {\cal P}(\Bbb N)\mid A\neq \{1\}\land A\neq \{2\}\}.$$

Comment: But there are $\aleph_1$ ways to partition $P(\mathbb N)$ no? so why is it only two?

Comment: @GinKin (There are actually $2^{\frak c}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}\ge\aleph_2$ ways to partition $P(\Bbb N)$.) However, in this case we were already told that *almost all* of the subsets end up in a single partition, leaving only two sets behind for us to partition as we wish. Thus there isn't anything we can do about the other uncountably many elements since they all go into one equivalence class by assumption.

Answer (score 2):

There are only two of them, precisely those for which equivalence classes are given by
$$ \{ \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})\setminus \{ \{ 1\}, \{ 2\}\}, \{\{ 1\}\}, \{\{ 2\}\}\}$$
and
$$ \{ \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})\setminus \{ \{ 1\}, \{ 2\}\}, \{\{ 1\}, \{ 2\}\}\}$$